# поле помеченное аннотацией @Transient попадает в сущность. как быть?

Tags: spring, jpa

Организована авторизация чз Spring-Sequrity. В сущности User использую аннотацию `@Transient` к полю проверки пароля (код ниже). В БД это поле не попадает, но если вытянуть этот объект из репозитория - то там это поле присутствует, что в частности мешает его дальнейшему сохранению через userRepo.save(userEntity): вылетает exception: `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction`

Попробовал исследовать этот вопрос, и, да, оказывается это нормальное поведение `@Transient`. Советы явно указывать аннотацию `@Transient` из `@javax.persistence.Transient` вместо `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` не помогают, как же, как и ключевое слово transient при объявлении поля.

Есть идеи, как предотвратить попадание поля `private String password2;` в репозиторий сущности, что бы можно было без проблем использовать (например) сохранение этой сущности, взятой из репозитория?

```
public String setOnlineData(String username) {
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        userEntity.setOnlineDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        userRepo.save(userEntity);   ///exception
        return "Successfully";
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Имя пользователя не может быть пустым!")
    private String username;
    @NotBlank(message = "Пароль не может быть пустым!")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    @NotBlank(message = "Пароль не может быть пустым!")
    private String password2;
    private boolean active;
    private LocalDateTime regDate;
    private LocalDateTime syncDate;
    private LocalDateTime onlineDate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private AmalgamationEntity curAmalgamation;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "t_user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Над полем `private String password2` стоят одновременно `@NotBlank` и `@Transient`, поэтому вот что происходит:

- перед первым сохранением в БД триггерится валидация, поле `password2` не пустое, валидация проходит успешно, но дальше из-за `@Transient` значение `password2` не сохраняется в БД (не передается в create SQL запрос)
- при выгрузке из БД из-за `@Transient` поле `password2` в созданном объекте `UserEntity` будет равно `null`
- при попытке сохранить такую сущность снова триггерится валидация и падает ошибка, т.к. поле помечено `@NotBlank`.
  Это кажется странным, т.к. не очень понятно зачем Spring валидирует поле, помеченное `@Transient`, но это так работает.

Чтобы избежать этого, я бы посоветовал в контроллерах использовать другой объект для валидации (DTO), в котором установить все необходимые для запроса правила, обработать необходимость наличия определенных полей, их равенство и т.п. И после успешной валидации мапить этот DTO на сущность и работать с ней в сервисе.
Т.к. очень странно иметь в классе сущности поле, которое для БД не имеет никакого значения.

Comment: я так же уже "решил" для себя этот вопрос (чз DTO), и жаль только потраченного времени на поиски других вариантов. поэтому отмечу ваш ответ как принятый. т.к. других вариантов вероятно нет. так же хочу добавить, что использование @Transient в JPA (@javax.persistence.Transient)  как по мне не имеет никакого смысла. по крайней мере в том виде, в котором оно сейчас организовано. не знаю как при других сериализациях, но с БД от этой аннотации больше проблем,)